# Heroku Deploy Failure Node app with process.env.PORT

Tags: node.js, heroku

I change express port, procfile seems ok and app still doesnt work.

Here are my files:
https://github.com/GDuccini/heroku

[Here is heroku log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9Wmb.png)

Answer (score 0):

You cut the interesting part of your log : the first line of your stack trace. 
By what I can see about your code, I would say that you didn’t add `models/articles.js` to git and heroku seems to crash because of an impossible `require` in your app.js file.
If it’s not that, please add your entire log file so that we can see the stack trace.